# Replacing the List table of a Post Type

Tags: admin, wp-list-table

Is there a way to replace the WP_List_Table object of a post type to display said post type differently on the Admin edit.php page?

Comment: Are you looking to add in extra columns, remove columns, what specifically is it you want to change about the WP_List_Table?

Comment: Not add columns but completely replace it with a custom UI

Comment: Well there are hooks available that allow you to put content above and below, edit things per row and/or column alongside the fact you can override with custom CSS & JS. Would that be the direction you want to go?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot replace the list table. There is no filter, everything is hard-coded.

But you can change the post type *registration*, set `show_ui` to `FALSE` to prevent the built-in page, and add a custom page for the post type listing to show the editable items.

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', function(){
    register_post_type(
        'test',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => 'TEST'
            ),
            'public' => TRUE,
            'show_ui' => FALSE
        )
    );
});

add_action( 'admin_menu', function(){
    add_object_page(
        'TEST',
        'TEST',
        'edit_test',
        'test',
        function(){
            echo 'test'; // list post type items here
        }
    );
});
```

Result

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 8):

This example is applied to `post` post type. This is leveraging the `WP_Posts_List_Table` class and `views-edit-{$post_type}` filter. This seem isn't the best way, but it works:

**Make sure the class is loaded on your page:**

```
if(!class_exists('WP_List_Table')){
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php' );
}
if(!class_exists('WP_Posts_List_Table')){
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-posts-list-table.php' );
}
```

**Extend the `WP_Posts_List_Table` class to remove list table and define the custom content:**

```
class wpse_CustomTable extends WP_Posts_List_Table
{       
    // remove search box
    public function search_box( $text, $input_id ){ }

    // Your custom list table is here
    public function display() {
        echo "Test";
    }
}
```

**Use it inside a filter hook:**

```
// hook into `views-edit`
add_filter( 'views_edit-post',  "sstssfb_custom_list_table");    
// Override the post table object
function sstssfb_custom_list_table() {
    global $wp_list_table;
    $mylisttable = new wpse_CustomTable();
    $wp_list_table = $mylisttable ;    
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Note that I adjusted my *table class extension example* [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/205281/26350), by calling the `prepare_items()` method . This would be needed for the pagination to work as expected. I also modified it with object *cloning*.

Comment: Thanks man appreciate your answer also works for me.