# How To Remove These Stuffs From Custom Post Type List Screen?

Tags: custom-post-types, list, wp-list-table

I am modifying a custom post type's post list screeen and I want to remove all of the stuffs on the tablenav head like what is marked in the following image.

[image]

Is wordpress have special hook for that, or will I need to use the dirty way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by *dirty way*, hopefully **not** core editing!

You can hide it with CSS.

Or you can do it with PHP - see below:

### Hide the views part

You can remove the *views* part with

```
add_filter( 'views_edit-post', '__return_null' );
```

for the `post` post type on the `edit.php` screen.

The post table object is created from:

```
$wp_list_table = _get_list_table('WP_Posts_List_Table');
```

but there's no filter available in the  `_get_list_table()` function.

### Workaround - Extending the `WP_Posts_List_Table` class

So here's a workaround by extending the `WP_Posts_List_Table` class and override it's methods within the `views_edit-post` filter - *Don't try this at home!* ;-)

```
/**
 * Headless post table
 * 
 * @link http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/205281/26350
 */
add_action( 'load-edit.php', function()
{
    // Target the post edit screen
    if( 'edit-post' !== get_current_screen()->id )
        return;

    // Include the WP_Posts_List_Table class
    require_once ( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-posts-list-table.php' );

    // Extend the WP_Posts_List_Table class and remove stuff
    class WPSE_Headless_Table extends WP_Posts_List_Table
    {
        public function search_box( $text, $input_id ){} // Remove search box
        protected function pagination( $which ){}        // Remove pagination
        protected function display_tablenav( $which ){}  // Remove navigation
    } // end class

    $mytable = new WPSE_Headless_Table; 
    // Prepare our table, this method has already run with the global table object
    $mytable->prepare_items();

    // Override the global post table object
    add_filter( 'views_edit-post', function( $views ) use ( $mytable )
    {
        global $wp_list_table;    
        // Let's clone it to the global object
        $wp_list_table = clone $mytable;
        // Let's remove the views part also
        return null;
    } );    
} );
```

Here's a screenshot example:

**Before:**

[image: before]

**After:**

[image: after]

Comment: Please be aware that this solution kills pagination on the list page (see screenshots provided by @birgire). The code can be modified to support pagination so the solution is absolutely viable. Just be sure to exercise caution.

Comment: yes it will remove the pagination, I just removed all the table navigation head, because of the OP's screenshot. But this is just an example how we could  adjust the table to our needs. @dswebsme

Comment: Absolutely. I just wanted to caution the copy/paste users so they'd know what to expect =] Certainly not implying there is anything wrong with the answer.

Comment: thanks for the caution, there are too many that just copy/paste - I also added a silly notice in the answer ;-) When only hiding stuff I would in general just recommend  CSS as you describe in your answer (+1) but this overriding method (just mentioned here for fun) might  be better suited for modifications that are not available through hooks/css ;-) @dswebsme

Comment: Using `css` or `jquery` is what I meant by using the dirty way.

Comment: @birgire how it work in custom post type, let's say it's portfolio post type

Comment: Good question, haven't looked into it, hope you're having success digging into it :-) @RendyAndriyanto

Answer (score 6):

The answer provided by @birgire is a solid programmatic way of handling the request but as he pointed out, his solutions gets a little tricky since WP core is missing an important filter.

To simply suppress, my preferred method would be CSS. Lets assume your custom post type is called "Event" this CSS will reliably do the trick:

```
.post-type-event .subsubsub,
.post-type-event .posts-filter .tablenav .actions,
.post-type-event .posts-filter .tablenav .view-switch,
.post-type-event .posts-filter .tablenav .tablenav-pages,
.post-type-event .posts-filter .search-box {
    display: none;
}
```

To ensure these styles are loaded on the WordPress dashboard be sure to enqueue it via the "admin_enqueue_scripts" hook using the wp_enqueue_style() helper.

EDIT: Updated the styles to separate "Actions" "View Icons" and "Pagination" into separate styles. Since pagination is pretty important I thought you might want to keep it. Simply deleting this line from the code above will show pagination but hide everything else:

```
.post-type-event .posts-filter .tablenav .tablenav-pages,
```

Comment: I see that your answer is from 2015, today I think the .posts-filter class no longer exists, you have to apply the style to the ID of the same name (form#posts-filter)