# On Users (user.php) in wp-admin disable/hide "Bulk Actions" and "Change Role To"

Tags: wp-admin, users

How do I disable or otherwise hide the row that displays "Bulk Actions" and "Change Role To"? I'd ideally prefer not to do it with CSS.

[image]

Comment: Seems the same as in the previous question. No action/filter you can hook into to do that. either edit core files (not recommended at all), or use css/js

Comment: Thanks @Buttered_Toast I'm getting back into WP after several years and getting back into things - thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How To Remove These Stuffs From Custom Post Type List Screen?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/205277/how-to-remove-these-stuffs-from-custom-post-type-list-screen)