# Replace admin edit.php content for CPT

Tags: custom-post-types

I am building a WP plugin and I want to replace the admin list page (*edit.php?post_type=my_cpt*) for my CPT. 
The CPT should not have any 'add new' buttons as new content will only be imported. The existing posts should still be editable and removable.
I can hide the 'add new' buttons and links by defining the capabilities of my CPT as follows:

```
'show_in_menu'     => 'my_cpt',
'capability_type'  => 'post',
    'capabilities' => array(
        'create_posts' => 'do_not_allow',       
    ),  
    'map_meta_cap' => true
```

I also created a custom menu with the same slug name as the CPT. (links to *admin.php?page=my_cpt_page*) and the default 'all posts' link is removed from the menu.

```
//Main menu (this page will have a custom table for my CPT)
add_menu_page(
    __( 'My CPT', 'cpt' ),                  // Page Title
    'My Test CPT',                          // Menu Title
    'edit_posts',                           // capability
    'my_cpt',                               // menu slug
     array( $this->main_page, 'render' ),    // action
    'dashicons-email-alt',                  // icon
    6                                       // position
); 
//remove menu created by wordpress
remove_submenu_page( 'my_cpt', 'edit.php?post_type=my_cpt' );
```

Now, when I go to an edit page of a single item (eg: *post.php?post=666&action=edit*) and I press the 'Move to Trash' link, Wordpress will redirect me to the hidden page located at *edit.php?post_type=my_cpt*.

Is there any way to redirect *edit.php?post_type=my_cpt* to my own custom page (*admin.php?page=my_cpt_page*) without altering the .htaccess file? Or, even better, is there a way to replace/override the edit.php screen for my CPT?

Thanks in advance

Vincent.

Comment: Note that you would need to recreate what `edit.php` does on your new page, as well as filter all the edit links, this isn't a trivial task ( although it is easier if you're using the block editor/gutenberg )

Comment: my custom page already has the necessary functionality. It has a custom WP_List_table and an import form above the table. My only goal is to add that import form above the table (without using Js/jQuery). 
I just found another way to manipulate the existing edit.php page by adding this filter: add_filter( 'views_edit-me_ctp',  "my_ctp_custom_list_table"); 
But the table views ('all','published','Trash') are gone from the table when I added this filter. How can I get the views back? (i am not using my custom table in this test).

Comment: Without seeing the way you used the filter it's not possible to answer that question. It also seems I misinterpreted your question, I thought you were talking about adding an edit page for your custom listing to link to that still conformed to your new URL

Comment: After playing around for more than a day I think I just found a solution by using the 'views_edit' filter which is using the built-in table. These two articles helped me: [replace post type table](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/205307) and [manipulate views](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/149143/hide-the-post-count-behind-post-views-remove-all-published-and-trashed-in-cus). I'll post an example as an answer after I have fully tested and validated my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to add html above the post type table which is generated by WP.

```
add_filter( 'views_edit-my_cpt', "custom_list_table"); 
function custom_list_table( $views ) {
    /* Print form */ ?>         
    <form method="post" action="//your.url/?action=action">
        <? wp_nonce_field( 'action-form', 'action_nonce' );  ?>     
        <label for="field1"><? _e('your label') ?></label><br />
        <input id="field1" type="text" name="field1"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submitbtn" class="button button-primary" value="<? _e('Go')?> ">
    </form><?   
    return $views;
}
```